# How to yield single item from a buffer of many items and periodically refill the buffer?

Tags: python, queue, generator

I have a large datasource from which I pull data, chunk by chunk.
Instead of returning a chunk of `chunksize` items, I want to yield a single item, via a generator, and once I have yield all the data from a chunk I want to load the next chunk.
The goal is to return one item at a time, without loading the full datasource, but also without pulling the items one by one from the datasource.

Here is some pseudo code:

```py
def get_data_chunk(datasource, chunksize=10):
    # grab chunksize elements of datasource
    return data_chunk # a list of dict, usually

def generator(datasource):
    data_chunk = get_data_chunk(datasource)
    for item in data_chunk:
        yield item
    # if no more item in data_chunk, reload from get_data_chunk
    # until datasource does not return anything
```

I tried to use a queue that I refill once empty, without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Either use a `while True:` loop and exit when the next chunk is empty:

   ```
   def generator(datasource):
       while True:
           data_chunk = get_data_chunk(datasource)
           if not data_chunk:
               return
           for item in data_chunk:
               yield item
   ```
2. Use the two-argument form of the [`iter()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) in a `for` loop:

   ```
   def generator(datasource):
       for data_chunk in iter(lambda: get_data_chunk(datasource), None):
           for item in data_chunk:
               yield item
   ```

   or, using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

   ```
   from itertools import chain

   def generator(datasource):
       chunk_iter = iter(lambda: get_data_chunk(datasource), None)
       yield from chain.from_iterable(chunk_iter)
   ```

The latter requires that you know what the 'end value' looks like. In the above, I assumed that that end value is `None`, but if it is an empty list, you need to replace `None` with `[]`.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, islice
>>> from random import randrange
>>> demosource = (randrange(11, 81) for _ in range(17))
>>> def get_data_chunk(datasource, chunksize=10):
...     return list(islice(datasource, chunksize))
...
>>> def generator(datasource):
...     chunk_iter = iter(lambda: get_data_chunk(datasource), [])  # last chuck is an empty list
...     yield from chain.from_iterable(chunk_iter)
...
>>> list(generator(demosource))
[38, 47, 74, 13, 23, 24, 47, 61, 30, 38, 70, 41, 43, 47, 37, 34, 67]
```